# Filter dataframe by factors based on users input in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I want the user of my shinyApp to select a variable, as well as the factors for this variable.

Then, the shinyApp will provide a dataset where the factors are filtered.

```
# Shiny
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinyjqui)
library(shinyjs)

# Data
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

# Plots
library(ggplot2)

not_sel <- "Not Selected"

ui <- navbarPage(
    tabPanel(
        "",
        fluidPage(
            fluidRow(
                sidebarPanel(
                    title = "Inputs",
                    fileInput("xlsx_input", "Select XLSX file to import", accept = c(".xlsx")),
                    selectInput("num_var_1", "Variable X axis", choices = c(not_sel)),
                    selectInput("num_var_2", "Variable Y axis", choices = c(not_sel)),
                    uiOutput("binning")
                ),
                
                # Main panel
                mainPanel(
                    tabsetPanel(
                        tabPanel(
                            "Plot",
                            br(),
                            plotOutput("plot_1"),
                            textOutput("test"),
                            uiOutput("levels")
                        ) 
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output){
    
    # Load data and update inputs
    data_input <- reactive({
        #req(input$xlsx_input)
        #inFile <- input$xlsx_input
        #read_excel(inFile$datapath, 1)
        warpbreaks
    })
    
    observeEvent(data_input(),{
        choices <- c(not_sel, names(data_input()))
        updateSelectInput(inputId = "num_var_1", choices = choices)
        updateSelectInput(inputId = "num_var_2", choices = choices)
    })
    
    num_var_1 <- reactive(input$num_var_1)
    num_var_2 <- reactive(input$num_var_2)
    
    # Select factors to display
    output$levels <-  renderUI({
        req(data_input(), input$num_var_1)
        e <- unique(data_input()[[input$num_var_1]])
        awesomeCheckboxGroup(inputId="levels", label = "Factor level order", choices = setNames(as.numeric(e), e), inline = TRUE)
    })
    
    data_plot <- reactive({
        req(data_input(), input$num_var_1, input$num_var_2)
        #df <- data_input()
        df<- data_input()[data_input()[[input$num_var_1]] %in% input$levels, ]
        df
    })
    
    output$test <- renderPrint(data_input())
}

# Connection for the shinyApp
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

However, the filtering function is not working, and I don't see why.
More precisely, this line of code:

```
df<- data_input()[data_input()[[input$num_var_1]] %in% input$levels, ]
```

In the case of the attached image, for example, the dataset should have the values for the factor F.

However, nothing is printed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please check the values of `input$levels`.

Try this

```
data_plot <- reactive({
    req(data_input(), input$num_var_1, input$num_var_2)
    #df <- data_input()
    df<- data_input()[as.numeric(data_input()[[input$num_var_1]]) %in% input$levels, ]
    df
  })
  
  output$plot_1 <- renderPlot({
    if (is.null(input$levels)) return(NULL)
    plot(data_plot())
  })
```